# Stubbing method using sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, sinon

I am trying to stub a method in sinon.

Here is a simplified example

```
function a() {
    return b().add(1, 'days');
}

function b() {
   return moment.utc();
}

module.exports = {
  a: a,
  b: b
};
```

I want to stub function `b()` to return a specific moment date when called from a file that has required it (e.g. `theFile.b()`) AND it should also be mocked internally when method `a()` is called.

I have tried the following

```
  sinon.stub(theFile, 'b').callsFake(function() {
    console.log("Calling mocked sinon ")
    return moment("2021-10-10", 'YYYY-MM-DD').utc().startOf('day');
  });
```

Which works when called externally but not when called internally in function `a()`.

I can see this is because sinon is overriding the module export but there must be a way around this. could anyone help?

---

Update

I have tried using the fakeTimers

```
function setMoockMomentDate(formattedDate) {
  const mockTimestamp =moment.utc(formattedDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").valueOf();
  console.log("Setting sinon to use " + mockTimestamp);
  const clock = sinon.useFakeTimers(mockTimestamp);
  clock.runAll();
}
```

which gets called at the start of the test.

The first function it calls updates something asynchronously in my firestore emulated database

These seems to hang because of the clock change.

Every example I have seen involves using a setTimeout with a predefined time period to wait e.g. 1000ms, which in my case I do not have.
e.g.

```
    console.log("Setting the fake date");
    setMoockMomentDate(startDateMocked);
    console.log("set the fake date");
    console.log(1)
    await testVariablesFile.func.updateFirestoreDoc(uid, {newKey: 'newVal'});
    console.log(2)


...
// other file

async function updateHasPhoto(uid, newVal) {
  const userDocRef = firestore.doc('users/' + uid);
  console.log("Starting update");
  await userDocRef.update(newVal);
  console.log("Finished update");
}
```

Is there a simple method of just mocking the system time and not breaking promises?

Comment: You would instead require `moment` and stub/spy `moment` directly. That being said, I wouldn't just stub/spy moment methods. You can instead use [sinon fake timers](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/fake-timers/) to set the date time that is used by any give test. This then allows you to make sure that the logic from beginning to end is working correctly, including actual dates/strings that moment would return and wouldn't require you to stub/spy moment at all.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for the help. I had a go with the fake timers but seem to have hit a wall with promises. I have updated my question if you wouldn't mind taking a look.

Comment: got it working using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockdate

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way: keep the same reference for function `b` in the original file and test file.

`index.js`:

```js
const moment = require('moment');

function a() {
  return exports.b().add(1, 'days');
}

function b() {
  return moment.utc();
}

exports.a = a;
exports.b = b;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const theFile = require('./');
const moment = require('moment');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('65081463', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    sinon.stub(theFile, 'b').callsFake(function() {
      console.log('Calling mocked sinon ');
      return moment('2021-10-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        .utc()
        .startOf('day');
    });
    const actual = theFile.a();
    console.log(actual);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  65081463
Calling mocked sinon 
Sun Oct 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0000
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (12ms)
```

Comment: Does exports.b() create a new object everytime it gets called? Like is there anything inefficient about doing this